# BlockedReason shows up empty

Tags: rally

What might I be missing in this example where I enhanced this simple app with a "Blocked" and "BlockedReason"?  No BlockedReason manifests on the grid even though I have such data.

```
                _queryForStories: function() {
                    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                        model: 'UserStory',
                        autoLoad: true,
                        fetch: ['Rank', 'FormattedID', 'Name', 'Blocked', 'BlockedReason'],
                        filters: [this.down('#iterationComboBox').getQueryFromSelected()],
                        sorters: [
                            {
                                property: 'Rank',
                                direction: 'ASC'
                            }
                        ],
                        listeners: {
                            load: this._onDataLoaded,
                            scope: this
                        }
                    });
                },

                _onDataLoaded: function(store, data) {
                    var records = [], rankIndex = 1;
                    Ext.Array.each(data, function(record) {
                        records.push({
                            Ranking: rankIndex++,
                            FormattedID: record.get('FormattedID'),
                            Name: record.get('Name'),
                            Blocked: record.get('Blocked'),
                            BlockedReason: record.get('BlockedReason')
                        });
                    });
```

...

```
                    if(!this.grid) {
                        this.grid = this.down('#grid').add({
                            xtype: 'rallygrid',
                            store: customStore,
                            columnCfgs: [
                                { text: 'Ranking', dataIndex: 'Ranking' },
                                { text: 'ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID' },
                                { text: 'Blocked', dataIndex: 'Blocked' },
                                { text: 'BlockedReason', dataIndex: 'BlockedReason', flex: 1 },
                                { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', flex: 1 }
                            ]
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the addition of a built-in BlockedReason field in our data model recently.  Anyone who had an existing BlockedReason field defined had it renamed to BlockedReasonDeprecated.  Additionally, the BlockedReason field is only available in web service versions 1.38 and above.

So you can either use BlockedReasonDeprecated as your field or if you're using SDK 2.0p4 or above you can include wsapiVersion: 1.38 in your WsapiDataStore config to use the new built-in field.